# What's a non app compat Xamarin application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking at this issue which is effecting me:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3087

It mentions that this is a problem with a

```
Steps to Reproduce

Just use a switch on a non app compat application
```

But what's a "non app compat application"

Also does anyone know any more about the history of this problem.  Is it just for Switch or for many other elements. Which version of Android is causing it? Looks like a big problem for anyone using an Android custom renderer.

Comment: AppCompat is most likely referring to `AppCompatActivity` or other various `AppCompat` features in the support libraries. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html a "non app compat" would refer to a plain `Activity`.

Comment: did you change activity class to appcompat? is it working now?

Comment: I didn't change it yet as I am still not sure where or how to change it.  Also not sure what's the advantage of setting it and what the difference is.  Do developers normally set or unset it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an explanation from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/#platform-support):

> Originally, the default Xamarin.Forms Android project used an older style of control renderering that was common prior to Android 5.0. Applications built using the template have `FormsApplicationActivity` as the base class of their main activity.

The sample project referenced in the github issue inherits from **FormsApplicationActivity** (non AppCompat):

```cs
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/#material-design-via-appcompat) also mention that modern projects use **AppCompat**:

> Xamarin.Forms Android projects now use `FormsAppCompatActivity` as the base class of their main activity. This class uses **AppCompat** features provided by Android to implement Material Design themes.